# Static method to turn shapes red

Tags: java

so i made this program and i am trying to add in my testing file a static method that turns a random array of shapes all "red".
public abstract class Shape
shape class

```
public abstract class Shape
{
private String color; 
public Shape() { color = "white";}
public String getColor() { return color;}
public void setColor(String c) { color = c; }
public abstract double area(); 
public abstract double perimeter();
public abstract void display();
}
```

circle class

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    private double radius;
    public Circle( double r)
    {
    super();
    radius = r;
    }
    public double getRadius()
    { return radius; }
    //Implement area, perimeter and display
    public double area()
    {
    return Math.PI * radius* radius;
    }
    public double perimeter()
    {
    return 2* Math.PI *radius;
    }
    //Circle class - continued
    public void display()
    {
    System.out.println( this);
    }
    public String toString()
    {


                return "Circle: radius:" + radius
                + "\tColor: " + getColor(); 

    }
}
```

my main class for testing

```
public class TestingShapes {

    public static double sumArea( Shape[] b)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for( int k = 0; k < b.length; k++)
        {
            sum = sum + b[k].area();

        }
        return sum;

    }
    public static void printArray( Shape[] b)
    {
    for (Shape u: b)
System.out.println(u + "\tArearea " +  u.area());
    System.out.println();
    }





    public static void main( String[] args)
    {
    Shape[] list = new Shape[20]; //Not creating Shapes
     for ( int k = 0 ; k < list.length; k++)
    {
    double z = Math.random();
    if( z < 0.33 )
    list[k] = new Circle(1 + Math.random() * 10);
    else if(z<0.66)
    list[k] = new Rectangle ( 3*(k+1), 4*(k+1), 5*(k+1),6*(k+1));
    else
    list[k] = new Triangle ( 3*(k+1), 4*(k+1), 5*(k+1));

    }

     printArray(list);
     System.out.println();
     double sum = sumArea(list);
     System.out.println("Sum of List Area: " + sum);
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how would i make a static method that would randomly turn some shapes red instead of white

Comment: @user2977404 Each shape has a method `setColor(String c)`. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

To turn some shapes randomly red, you would create a method accepting the array of shapes, and loop over it. You can use `Math.random()` to get a random floating point number between 0 and 1. To turn, say, 20% of shapes red, you would just compare `Math.random()` to 20%: `if (Math.random() < 0.2) { call the shape's setColor method with "red" }`. Since arrays/collections in Java are passed by reference, you don't need to return anything from the method, it will modify the copy that the caller owns.